# ROC vs Lift chart

Tags: machine-learning, model, roc

The advantage of ROC over lift chart is stated as below:
"Lift is dependent on total response rate of the population. Hence, if the response rate of the population changes, the same model will give a different lift chart. A solution to this concern can be true lift chart (finding the ratio of lift and perfect model lift at each decile). But such ratio rarely makes sense for the business.

ROC curve on the other hand is almost independent of the response rate. This is because it has the two axis coming out from columnar calculations of confusion matrix. The numerator and denominator of both x and y axis will change on similar scale in case of response rate shift."

Can someone please elaborate on this using an example for case where lift chart fails and ROC doesn't?

Comment: @LernerZhang link broken

Comment: @BenReiniger Yes, but I cannot find the paper either.